# User Spatial Point column OR not in MySQL for Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation, spatial

I am using MySQL in my application to store a list of cities.
each long/lat represent the center of the city.

I want to be able to pull all cities that are close to a specific city by the distance of X kilometers.

My question is what will be performing faster for that purpose.

- Using the Point column, and use "spatial" queries to retrieve the data ?

OR

- Using a Float Longitude column And Float Latitude column. and then use java code to generate the long/lat between distance before running the SQL WHERE BETWEEN query on those values .

Another small question I have, does it make sense to request all cities that are 10 Kilometers from New York. When New York range is probably bigger then 10 kilometers?

Comment: spatial extension will always be faster than `BETWEEN`, since it uses R-Tree indexes, whereas mysql's native ones are B-Tree

Comment: "dose i make sense to request all cities that are 10Kilometers from New York. when new york range is probably bigger then 10 kilometers" --- depending on how you're defining the "New York". Any particular point? A polygon?

Comment: For very close cities, this may work a bit. However, as we're not in a 2 dimensional plane but on a sphere, the results will be a bit off close by, and _way_ off further away.

Comment: @zerkms i define "new york" also as a point, i don't have the rage  information in kilometers on all cities in the world , didn't ind anyone provide that information. and i am not sure if i need that information... this way i am asking for feedback

Comment: @zerkms can u place an answer so i can mark your answer as correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial extension will always be better in this case, since it's based on R-Tree indexes, which are optimized for range search in N-dimensional space.

Whereas native mysql indexes are B-Tree and in the best case only one field from the index will be used (for the range comparison), or no index at all (in case if you use some advanced geo formulas like in another answer).

Comment: ok i think i got it :)
SELECT count(*) FROM c c WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon((1.3 42,1.3 40,-1.3 40,-1.3 42, 1.3 42))'),c.location);  return in 0.016 sec For '3,173,959' rowssssss :-)

Comment: @shay te: `0.016 sec For '3,173,959' rowssssss` --- that's impressive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**Haversine formula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to query the database.

The query below is using **PDO**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM mytable HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");

// Assign parameters
$stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
```

Where

1. 6371 is the radius of Earth in km
2. $center_lat & $center_lng cordinates of location
3. $center_lng radius of search

This query took 1.93 secs to run on a 457K row unindexed database.

```
name Varchar(50) 
lat Decimal(9,6)
lng Decimal(9,6)
```

Comment: It's barely acceptable for anything that's bigger than 100k rows

Comment: thank you , but what of the mention method will be best to implement

Comment: @shayte   Store coordinates Decimal(9,6). Decimal is accurate, Float is approximate [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html)

Comment: @davidstrachan thanks i just learned something new :-), but what happens with spatial Point column ?

Comment: @shayte The query uses MySQL without the spatial extention. As you can see the query runs at < 2secs for 457K row database without indexes.

Comment: @david strachan: and 2 seconds is **A LOT** for just 500k rows.

Comment: When using spatial indexing SELECT count(*) FROM c c WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon((1.3 42,1.3 40,-1.3 40,-1.3 42, 1.3 42))'),c.location); return in 0.016 sec For '3,173,959' rows :-)

Comment: I Think as others are saying, using spatial is faster, but also it looks like this doesn't even answer OP question.